# How to draw a 3D grid using matplotlib based on three columns of data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm facing a problem with making a 3D plot. I want to build a 3D surface plot like below from three columns of data.
[Expected graphic case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWDZR.png)

I have implemented a few currently, as shown below.
[Current picture case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFGdC.png)
But I still don't know how to make it "grid" like the first picture? Does anyone know how to achieve this? Part of the code and full data are as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import warnings
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
os.chdir(r"E:\SoftwareFile\stataFile")
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

data = pd.read_stata(r"E:\SoftwareFile\stataFile\demo.dta")

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

ax.plot_trisurf(data["age"], data["weight"], data["pr_highbp"],
cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r)


ax.set_xticks(np.arange(20, 90, step=10))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(40, 200, step=40))
ax.set_zticks(np.arange( 0, 1.2, step=0.2))

ax.set_title("Probability of Hypertension by Age and Weight")
ax.set_xlabel("Age (years)")
ax.set_ylabel("Weight (kg")
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax.set_zlabel("Probability of Hypertension", rotation=90)

ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=240)
plt.savefig("demo.png", dpi=1200)
```

[Download all data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BjTWFJ0NJ3391j81MQrsy_S0eSADex9p/view?usp=sharing)
Sincerely appreciate your help

Comment: Please add the code you wrote to create that plot... I think youre almost there.. currently the code in your answer just seems to read the data?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I have edited as suggested.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the colormap and opacity in the trisurf command like so:

```
ax.plot_trisurf(
data["age"],
data["weight"],
data["pr_highbp"],
color=None,
linewidth=1,
antialiased=True,
edgecolor="Black",
alpha=0,
)
```

That should result in:

[image: Trisurf wireframe]

You could also take a look at `plot_wireframe()`. For that I think you have to start with

```
x = data["age"].to_list()
y = data["weight"].to_list()
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

But I'm not sure how to create the z coordinate. It seems you may need interpolation from what I read.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and guidance, they are inspiring.

Comment: Hello, if I want to remove the diagonal lines in each small rectangle, I need to learn `plot_wireframe()`, right?

Comment: @ManfredL Yes, that function uses rectangles.. try it out

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I tried to learn `plot_wireframe()` before, but it requires Z to be 2D arrays, but my Z is directly from demo.dta (Z is calculated via stata), which makes me hesitate. Would `plot_wireframe()` be ok to load Z directly? Or is there another idea? If so, I would feel confident to learn `plot_wireframe()`

Comment: @ManfredL I don't know, sorry. I looked into it but I don't understand what form the Z coordinate has to have. I added a starting point to my answer.

Comment: Your guidance is important and I have resolved it. `plot_wireframe()` requires Z to be 2D arrays, transform the data and then use it.

Comment: @ManfredL Great, could you outline how you transformed it? Also, feel free to upvote/accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: ```
xx = data['x']
yy = data['y']
zz = data['z']
x = np.array(xx)
y = np.array(yy)
z = np.array(zz)
ldz_hang = 46 #This needs to be filled in manually according to the data
ldz_ge = 33 ##This needs to be filled in manually according to the data
x.resize((ldz_hang, ldz_ge))  
y.resize((ldz_hang, ldz_ge))  
z.resize((ldz_hang, ldz_ge))  
```
Thank u.